# Struggling understanding IELTS reading comprehension answer key

Tags: sentence-meaning, british-english, reading-comprehension, ielts

I need some help with explaining this IELTS reading exercise.

The question from the exercise is: Rocket as war weapons were first invented or used by ________?

The options are:

- a. The Chinese
- b. The Indians
- c. The British
- d. The Arabs
- e. The Americans

The answer key for that question is **(c) the Indians**.

Reading the article, the Indians is not the only who use rocket as war weapons, there are also the Chinese, British and Americans. My question is what's the explanation of this? Why the answer is only Indians?

I got a problem understanding the answer key. As I read from the reading, Indians is not the only one who used rocket as war weapon (also not the first inventors), there are also the Chinese, the British and the Americans.

Maybe I misread or misunderstood or I have not mastering the article. Please help me!

Here is the article for this question:

> The invention of rockets is linked inextricably with the invention of 'black powder'. 
>   Most historians of technology credit the Chinese with its discovery. They base their 
>   belief on studies of Chinese writings or on the notebooks of early Europeans who 
>   settled in or made long visits to China to study its history and civilisation. It is 
>   probable that, some time in the tenth century, black powder was first compounded 
>   from its basic ingredients of saltpetre, charcoal and sulphur. But this does not mean 
>   that it was immediately used to propel rockets. By the thirteenth century, powder-
>   propelled fire arrows had become rather common. The Chinese relied on this type of 
>   technological development to produce incendiary projectiles of many sorts, explosive 
>   grenades and possibly cannons to repel their enemies. One such weapon was the 
>   'basket of fire' or, as directly translated from Chinese, the 'arrows like flying leopards'. 
>   The 0.7 metre-long arrows, each with a long tube of gunpowder attached near the 
>   point of each arrow, could be fired from a long, octagonal-shaped basket at the same 
>   time and had a range of 400 paces. Another weapon was the 'arrow as a flying 
>   sabre', which could be fired from crossbows. The rocket, placed in a similar position 
>   to other rocket-propelled arrows, was designed to increase the range. A small iron 
>   weight was attached to the 1.5m bamboo shaft, just below the feathers, to increase 
>   the arrow's stability by moving the centre of gravity to a position below the rocket. At 
>   a similar time, the Arabs had developed the 'egg which moves and burns'. This 'egg' 
>   was apparently full of gunpowder and stabilised by a 1.5m tail. It was fired using two 
>   rockets attached to either side of this tail.
>
> It was not until the eighteenth century that Europe became seriously interested in the 
>   possibilities of using the rocket itself as a weapon of war and not just to propel other 
>   weapons. Prior to this, rockets were used only in pyrotechnic displays. The incentive 
>   for the more aggressive use of rockets came not from within the European continent 
>   but from far-away India, whose leaders had built up a corps of rocketeers and used 
>   rockets successfully against the British in the late eighteenth century. The Indian 
>   rockets used against the British were described by a British Captain serving in India 
>   as ‘an iron envelope about 200 millimetres long and 40 millimetres in diameter with 
>   sharp points at the top and a 3m-long bamboo guiding stick’. In the early nineteenth 
>   century the British began to experiment with incendiary barrage rockets. The British 
>   rocket differed from the Indian version in that it was completely encased in a stout, 
>   iron cylinder, terminating in a conical head, measuring one metre in diameter and 
>   having a stick almost five metres long and constructed in such a way that it could be 
>   firmly attached to the body of the rocket. The Americans developed a rocket, 
>   complete with its own launcher, to use against the Mexicans in the mid-nineteenth 
>   century. A long cylindrical tube was propped up by two sticks and fastened to the top 
>   of the launcher, thereby allowing the rockets to be inserted and lit from the other end. 
>   However, the results were sometimes not that impressive as the behaviour of the 
>   rockets in flight was less than predictable.

Comment: “rocket as” or “**rockets** as”?   It seems like your example has a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you seem to have missed in the question is *first*:

> Rocket as war weapons were **first** invented or used by ________?

Note: It doesn't ask who first invented rockets, or who used them as a war weapon. The question asks, "Who first used it as a war weapon?"

The answer to this question can be found in the third sentence of the second paragraph:

> The incentive for the more aggressive use of rockets came not from within the European continent but from far-away India, whose leaders had built up a corps of rocketeers and used rockets successfully against the British in the late eighteenth century.